# Database-Trigger to Delete row where condition is True:

Tags: mysql

I need trigger That Deletes row where in table `paym` both columns `table1` and `table2` are not empty.

Example in tables below:
table: `paym`

```
 ID        username        table1        Table2  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   1   |  John       |  Value      |    Value  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  Alex       |  Null       |    Null   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Condition is True: And Deleted row:

```
 ID        username        table1        Table2  
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|   2   |  Alex       |  Null       |    Null   |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

**My attemp is:** Not working

```
CREATE trigger DeleteROW
AFTER UPDATE ON paym
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.table1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.table2 IS NOT NULL) THEN
          DELETE
    FROM
        paym WHERE table1 and table2 IS NOT NULL ;
        END IF;
    END
```

Comment: Malformed expression:  `table1 and table2 IS NOT NULL` -- it is equivalent to `( table1 ) and ( table2 IS NOT NULL )`

Answer (score -1):

You only need to delete all rows with that condition in one step.

```
CREATE trigger DeleteROW
AFTER UPDATE ON paym
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     DELETE FROM paym WHERE table1 IS NOT NULL AND table2 IS NOT NULL;
  END
```

Notice that the action is performed with every inserted row.

Comment: Omar Alvarado now working!!

Comment: *... AFTER UPDATE ON **paym** ... DELETE FROM **paym** ... * - not allowed.